# $geoNear error when trying to find the near users

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ecmascript-6

When I am trying to run this code with other aggregation objects, it fails when getting near users. error it give me is **MongoServerError: geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 16093.4**

Here is my code when it makes an error:

```
let aggregatePipeline = [];
aggregatePipeline.push({
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [longitude, latitude],
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      spherical: true,
      maxDistance: radius,
      //minDistance: <number in meters>, you can also add minimum distance to this aggregation
    },
  });
```

here is where I run my pipeline:

```
const sellers= await Seller.aggregate(aggregatePipeline).exec();
```

and here is the model for my seller schema:

```
const sellerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  ...,
  location: {
    type: { type: String, default: "Point" },
    coordinates: [], // ! <longitude, latitude> ex. coordinates [47, 23.224434]
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

I might be running the $geoNear incorrectly or maybe I can use another argument.

Comment: It looks OK, please provide a sample document and the actual query (with the values)

Comment: I found out the issue. It was me not parsing the request body that I was retrieving. For example, limit is in form of string (needs to parseInt) and same for lat, lng (convert to float). The issue was solved after that. I was thinking about it all day, for such simple mistake lol Thank you for the help.